# Adding limits to regression coefficients

Tags: multiple-regression, constrained-regression

For my problem, I have data that contains daily observations of the total time and the volumes of task A completed, task B completed, C, D.. and I am looking to estimate the time it takes to solve task A, B, C, D etc.

[total time] = [task A time]*[volumes A] + [task B time][volumes B] + [task C time][volumes C] + ..  
Where [total time] and all [volumes _].. Are known.

Since I have tried multiple regression on this with total time as the [total time] and volumes as the independent variable but have been getting a values that are too high or too low for the coefficients (i.e. [task _ time].

I know roughly the upper and lower range for the time for each task e.g. 200 < [task A time] < 400. Is regression the best way to approach this problem and is there a way to factor these limits on the coefficients in the regression?

[image: edit: this is what the data looks like]

Comment: Is your question about the use of limits on the *coefficients* or on the *dependent variable?*  You seem to be saying both.

Comment: Just the coefficients

Comment: When you say you have been getting wide range of coefficients, do you mean confidence interval for each coefficient or you are getting substantially different estimates from different datasets?

Comment: Is total time taken the sum of all times for the tasks A to N?

Comment: Please clarify your question: it still sets limits on the *dependent variables* and asks whether there is a "way to factor these limits" in to the procedure.  That's ambiguous and confusing.

Comment: @whuber Ah sorry, I see the confusion. The equation is [total time] = [task A time]*[task a volumes] + [task B time][task b vol] + [task C time][task C vol] + .. . The unknowns I'm trying to estimate are [task a time], [task b time]. [total time] and [task a volumes], [task b volumes] .. are known.

Comment: @Dayne sorry poor wording - I meant to say that the coefficient estimates are too high or low from what I expect should be possible

Comment: @user2974951 it should look like [total time] = [task A time]*[volumes A] + [task B time][volumes B] + [task C time][volumes C] + ..

Comment: In that case maybe you should consider interaction term or any other variable. Check for residuals for any left over correlation with your explanatory variables. Adding limits to coefficients would just increases the error term and will not be a good fit. If naturally a good estimate is not coming then there is likely to be specification error.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the question is now rather clear

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you are asking. However, constraints for parameters are routine but only for certain regression methods. Also, the availability of routines that include constraints varies somewhat between platforms. For example, in Mathematica, [constrained optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationIntroduction.html) can be applied for a number of regression methods including Nelder-Mead, and differential evolution. R-language, has for example, a [constrained optimization](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/constrOptim.html) algorithm. IBM's SPSS GENLIN MIXED has constrained optimization for the Newton-Raphson method using Active SET Method (ASM).

The practical information you require is to do a search for whatever platform you are using the search term `constrained optimization`.

Comment: Thanks Carl, I had a look at the approach using R but am a bit confused as to how to implement this using my data but I'll keep at it

Answer (score 1):

I remember using a levenberg-marquardt algorithm in R, using the minpack.lm package, which was extremely easy to constrain coefficients.  Although I observed some coefficients seemed to rush towards my set bounds!

This was the best I could research given box constrained regression, usually refers to set bounds of the minimum in the error surface. I think.